# Gnome-terminal color inversion

Tags: colors, gnome-terminal, htop

I have some custom colours set up inside gnome-terminal, basically light text on dark background.

The problem is, some programs interact badly with the colors. For example, `htop` uses very light green/blues for highlighting text, but the text itself is not inverted so it's very poorly visible - see image [image: see image].

Now, I'd expect that there is some kind of protocol that tells htop (or vim etc.) whether to invert text color. The thing is, I don't want to customize colors in all applications. I'd expect them to know to select something that's reasonable. Highlighting light text with a light background is not reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECMA-48 standard (and ISO/IEC 6429, and ANSI X3.64) defines a 16-color palette with *specific colors* – black, red, green, yellow, blue, purple, cyan, white. In your screenshot, htop asks the terminal to use palette entry #1 as foreground, and palette entry #7 as background.

The choice therefore *is* reasonable, since #1 on #7 will result in black-on-cyan in any compliant terminal emulator. The programs have *no* way of knowing that you have changed the "black" slot to something that's nearly white.

---

GNOME Terminal has separate settings for default foreground & background colors. If you want the terminal to be black-on-white, change those settings, instead of redefining the regular slots to be what they aren't.

And if some programs explicitly select black as the general background, see if you can change the color scheme in those programs. In htop, press <kbd>F2</kbd> and pick "Monochromatic" or "Black on White" or "Light Terminal" as the color scheme.